# how to debug a stuck migration

Tags: spring, grails, migration

I'm working on a project with a legacy grails stack, and having problems starting the app, it fails on specific migrations

```
grails dbm-status
```

Is failing for me on a specific migration (I think?)

```
| Error Error executing script DbmUpdate: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication': 
Bean instantiation via constructor failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication]: 
Constructor threw exception; 
nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: 

Class not found loading Grails application: v0212.changelog 
(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

So I think the top is all just 'something failed' and the specific is that the migration named `v0212.changelog` cannot be found. However the migration IS in my project, and identical to all the other migrations that I can see.

What else can I do to poke around on this? 
- how can I find the "current" migration
- how to startup grails and NOT try to run all the migrations?

FWIW `grails console` also fails with the same error.

I tried removing some other migrations, and the app will just fail on the next one.
I tried deleting the whole migrations folder and somehow it still fails looking for that same file.

```
▶ grails --version
Grails version: 2.5.6

▶ java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

▶ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.47, for osx10.15 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: Try a grails clean to see if the issue goes away. it seems like the changelog was compiled somehow to a class and the app is loking for it. Also run with --stacktrace and include that.

Comment: I think this was it, I had to `rm -rf target`. I guess groovy just doesn't really compile things reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails migration plugin will create `databasechangelog` table in the database. You can simply query the table to check about the last executed migration script by executing the below command:

```
select * from databasechangelog
order by orderexecuted desc;
```

Comment: that certainly helped to find out what's going on!